# Съезжает контент сайта

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

В общем только пару недель изучаю сайтостроение, и вот такая проблема при изменении масштаба в браузере весь контент смешается влево, не надо мне тут писать что margin: 0 auto; поможет пробовал нихрена не помогает, подскажите что-то поэффективней

Comment: **[Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**

Comment: Без кода никто не поможет. А вкратце у вас нет адаптивности сайта.

Comment: учи css, поверь, самый эффективный вариант...  а тут на подобные вопросы без кода не смогут помоч...  тут люди обычные, не ясновидящие...

Comment: я вас считать стал)))  ты сегодня шестой)))

Comment: Скрины? Ссылки на сайт? Код ?

Answer (score 1):

Какой вопрос такой ответ.

Для того чтобы предать нужному блоку какое либо свойство  при смене ширины экрана используйте медиа запросы.

```
@media screen and (max-width: ширина например 768px) {
    Элемент {
        Свойство : значение 
    }
}
```

Для того чтобы текст не смешался в лево или вправо сделайте родительский контейнер шириной в 100%, текст ширину в 100% так же сделайте *position:relative;* добавьте *left:0; right:0; text-align: left; margin:0* !important; padding:0 !important; сделайте на родительский блок *display:table* например, так же попробуйте менять *font-size*.

Для более конкретного и детального ответа, нужно смотреть на код или открыть саму страницу.

Начните изучать адаптивный дизайн. Изучайте [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), читайте книги, статьи по [HTML и CSS](https://proglib.io/p/html-css-collection/).

Самый верный ответ ты найдешь самостоятельно изучив HTML и CSS как правильно сказал [@Air](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/211549/air) - "Учи css, поверь, самый эффективный вариант."

Comment: **справка - [Не на все вопросы стоит отвечать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)**

Comment: @Alex,  Да читал :)